# Problems Installing XCRYSDEN in CYGWIN

Tags: software-installation, cygwin

I am trying to install XCrySDen on my computer (Windows) and I am using cygwin for this. I am following the instructions perfectly:

```
> $ tar xvf xcrysden-1.5.53.tar.gz
$ cd xcrysden-1.5.53/
$ cp system/Make.sys-shared Make.sys
$ make all
$ ./xcrysden
```

I am getting the following error message:

```
 +-----------------------------------------------------------------+
|*****************************************************************|
|*                                                               *|
|*  XCrySDen -- (X-Window) CRYstalline Structures and DENsities  *|
|*               =         ===         =              ===        *|
|*---------------------------------------------------------------*|
|*                                                               *|
|*    Anton Kokalj (tone.kokalj@ijs.si)                          *|
|*    Jozef Stefan Institute, Ljubljana, Slovenia                *|
|*                                                               *|
|*    Copyright (c) 1996--2019 by Anton Kokalj                   *|
|*                                                               *|
|*****************************************************************|
+-----------------------------------------------------------------+

  Version: 1.6.2

  Please report bugs to: tone.kokalj@ijs.si


  TERMS OF USE:
  -------------
  XCRYSDEN is released under the GNU General Public License.

  Whenever graphics generated by XCRYSDEN are used in scientific
  publications, it shall be greatly appreciated to include an explicit
  reference. The preferred form is the following:

  [ref] A. Kokalj, J. Mol. Graph. Model., Vol. 17, pp. 176-179, 1999.
        Code available from http://www.xcrysden.org/.

XCRYSDEN_TOPDIR=/cygdrive/c/Users/itsas/Downloads/xcrysden-1.6.2
XCRYSDEN_SCRATCH=/tmp

./xcrysden: line 275: /cygdrive/c/Users/itsas/Downloads/xcrysden-1.6.2/bin/xcrys: No such file or directory
```

I have tried installing the newer version of XCrySDen and I get the same error. I am unsure about how to fix this. I have also tried doing it in WSL (Ubuntu) and still gave the same output.

Comment: does `xcrys` esist in the bin directory ?

Answer (score 0):

**This is a solution for Mac**

1. Download and unpack the source packages [here](http://www.xcrysden.org/doc/install.html)
2. Download the binary packages [here](http://www.xcrysden.org/Download.html), in addition to the source package, and unpack.
3. Run in x window (I did this by opening XQuartz from Terminal by running `xterm`)
4. `cd` to `xcrysden-1.6.2-bin-shared`
5. then type `./xcrysden`

Comment: XQuartz? I take it this is on a Mac, right, and not on a Windows system?

Comment: Yes that is correct.